# AWS CloudFront | Invalidations

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, invalidation

I am using a single CloudFront to serve multiple domains (*.domain.com), this CloudFront uses an API server as an origin.

Any request made to a domain say, test1.domain.com to goes to the API server and depending on the host header we send the response back.

Now, if I want to purge the cache, **I can't run it for a specific domain** ( as CloudFront only allows path invalidation like */users/** or */users/*/books*).

Note: I don't want to purge the entire cache (*/**), as it would cause performance issues.

Did someone face this situation?